# How to turn each element of array into a square root and sum them up

Tags: javascript, arrays, math.sqrt

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript and I have to do a task:

Create function with local variables which turns each element of array [0,1,2,3,4,5] into a sqrt and sums them up.

I know how to do a function and then I have to do a loop - I have a problem with the next step and using Math.sqrt...

```
function myFunction() {  
   var numbers = ['0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
   var total = 1;

   for (var i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        var result = Math.sqrt(numbers[i++]) * +numbers[i];
        console.log(result);
   }
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: First you may want to consider making the elements of the `numbers` array numbers, rather than strings.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan he did actually allow for that, but at the moment the loop isn't actually summing anything

Comment: `numbers.map(function(strNumber) { return Math.sqrt(parseInt(strNumber)) })        .reduce(function(prev, num) { return prev + num }, 0)`

Comment: @Alnitak I realize that, but what's the point of making them strings, only to convert them to numbers again?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan indeed - it would be better if the numbers were actually numbers in the first place

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks a lot!!! I see now such simple mistakes... ok so Math.sqrt(numbers[i]) gives me each sqrt how do I add each one? Do I have to split them?

Comment: @Alnitak  thanks too, I changed them to numbers.

Comment: @asheri did you actually try reading the answers given here, yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP is in the early stages of learning how to use JavaScript I present a straight forward external iteration based method below. While the other answer presents a declarative approach, it seems important for the OP to get a handle on the basics first.

```
function sumSquareRoots(numbers) {  
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        var sqrt = Math.sqrt(numbers[i]);
        total = total + sqrt;
   }
   return total;
}

var numbers = ['0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
var result = sumSquareRoots(numbers);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to return the result, and print it from outside, rather than printing it inside.

Comment: The OP just logged the result to the console. No mention of returning the result.

Comment: @bhspencer thanks so much, I indeed needed something simple since I'm just starting. I understand now what I did wrong!

Answer (score 4):

This (ES2015 syntax) function will sum the square roots of an array of numbers:

```
let sumRoots = array => array.map(Math.sqrt).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

The [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is the standard way to transmogrify the elements of an array into a (new) modified array, and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is used to collapse the resulting array into its sum.

If you can't handle ES2015 syntax, get a better browser, or use this:

```
function sumRoots(array) {
    return array.map(Math.sqrt)
                .reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return a + b;
                }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Like my comment, but without handling the string numbers

Comment: Why not just `a.reduce((a, b) => a + Math.sqrt( b ) ), 0);`? It seems unesseccary to map when each element is visited during the reduce anyway.

Comment: @Paulpro  The map followed by the reduce is more semantic. it better captures the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Paulpro yeah, I considered that, but I figured the two step process is easier to understand

Comment: @torazaburo how so? Paulpro's suggestion is more optimal without losing any readability.

Comment: The code as it stands correctly separates the concerns of (1) some computation involving each element and (2) adding up the results of those computations. If the problem were changed to add up squares, it would be trivial to change `map(Math.sqrt)` to `map(square)`.

Comment: @torazaburo right - this is the "functional programmer's" approach to the problem

Comment: @Alnitak thanks but using map may be a little to difficult to me ATM but I will keep studying :)

Comment: @asheri stick with it - learning the standard library functions will result in better code

Answer (score 0):

```
    function myFunction() {  
    var numbers = ['0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    var sum=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += Math.sqrt(numbers[i]);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}

myFunction();
```

Is that you looking for?

Comment: yes, it's good! I quess I overlooked the part with 
"sum+= etc " :) Thanks! It's so simple hahaha

Answer (score 0):

```
  var sum = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
                                    .reduce((a,b)=>(a+Math.sqrt(b)),0);
```

For this you have to understand internally mechanism of `reduce` method .  in this method the value of `b` is always array element . where

> in each iteration   a =return value.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply map through and multiply each item by its self.

```
let numbers = ['0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
let storeMultipliedIndex = []
numbers.map(item => storeMultipliedIndex.push(item * item))
console.log(storeMultipliedIndex)
```